# Enabling FreeOTP login with Spring Boot API and Keycloak

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak, totp

```
@PutMapping("/users/{userId}/enable-otp")
public ResponseEntity<String> enableOtp(@PathVariable String userId) throws JsonProcessingException {
    UserResource userResource = keycloak.realm("google").users().get(userId);
    UserRepresentation user = userResource.toRepresentation();
    CredentialRepresentation credential = new CredentialRepresentation();
    credential.setType(CredentialRepresentation.TOTP);
    credential.setValue(null); // Set to null to let Keycloak generate the secret key
    keycloak.realm("google").users().get(user.getId()).resetPassword(credential);
    String generatedSecretKey = user.getAttributes().get("otp_secret").get(0);
    user.setAttributes(Collections.singletonMap("otp_secret", Collections.singletonList(generatedSecretKey)));
    keycloak.realm("google").users().get(userId).update(user);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("OTP enabled for user " + userId);
}
```

this function do not work for me it return status 200 but it do not enable user to login with freeOtp Application

I want to allow users to login using the FreeOTP application for two-factor authentication in my Spring Boot application
I have successfully integrated Keycloak with my Spring Boot API and enabled regular username/password authentication. However, I'm unsure how to enable FreeOTP login specifically
I'm using keycloak 16.1.1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.